# global.asax nlog

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, global-asax, nlog

I am trying to log the end of a web application(with nlog) and I try to do it in Global.asax  Application_End(). Unfortunately the application domain is not available there anymore, and nlog fails detecting the application name. Is there a specific event fired before Application_End() that I can use the logging from within?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use the [HttpApplication.Dispose](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpapplication.dispose%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) method.

As described in [ASP.NET Application Life Cycle Overview for IIS 5.0 and 6.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178473%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), the `Dispose` method is called before `Application_End`.

I know this is for IIS 5.0 and  6.0, but as described in [ASP.NET Application Life Cycle Overview for IIS 7.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb470252%28v=vs.100%29.aspx#GlobalAsax) it is the same for IIS 7.0.